# Bootstrap-sass on Rails can't scroll pages on mobile browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

Most of my app won't let me scroll at all and it cuts off a lot of content. The one exception is on the home page, where I use skrollr. I hope that's not causing a conflict.

After installing Bootstrap-Sass, the app wasn't being responsive at all to mobile (everything was tiny) and I had to add this to application.html.erb:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I don't know if that has something to do with it. Maybe I need to set a device-height?

Everything works fine on my desktop browser. If I shrink the browser there, I can scroll fine.

Anyone ever experience this or have any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that skrollr was causing the problem. I was initializing it everywhere when I should have only been initializing it on the page I need.